# Remove Featured Image & All Media Uploaded to the Post

Tags: posts, images, post-thumbnails, media, trash

I found a solution of removing featured image related to the post when delete the post from [this article](https://www.isitwp.com/remove-featured-image-deleting-post/) but, I want to remove all the uploaded media also with post removing. Delete all WP image gallery (included generated thumbnails) that are attached to a post. How can I do this?

Comment: This is the code:https://gist.github.com/mohsinworld/6d3d93f1d3289325d36c2f495bc6d7ae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the function [`get_attached_media()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_media/) like this:

```
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'wps_remove_attachment_with_post', 10 );
function wps_remove_attachment_with_post( $post_id ) {

    /** @var WP_Post[] $images */
    $images = get_attached_media( 'image', $post_id );

    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
        wp_delete_attachment( $image->ID, true );
    }
}
```

**Note that this will permanently delete all the image files related to this post. If those attachments are used somewhere else as well, those links will be broken.**

Comment: Great thanks for this help